# Robust rwlock in posix

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, posix

Posix provides a mechanism for a mutex to be marked as "robust", allowing multi-processes systems to recover gracefully from the crash of a process holding a mutex.

```
pthread_mutexattr_setrobust(&mutexattr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST);
```

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_mutexattr_setrobust.3.html

However, there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for rwlock (reader-writer locks).

How can a process gracefully recover from a process crashing while holding a `rwlock`?

Comment: You can roll your own RW locks using `sys v` semaphores.  Use the UNDO flag with the semaphores to recover from crashed process (it allows the system to "undo" the semaphore operations the process had performed)

Comment: It should also be possible to roll your own rwlocks with a robust mutex and condvar or POSIX semaphore. Using sysv semaphores is going to be 1000x slower just because every operation is a syscall.

Comment: @R.. do you have citation for the speed difference?  I've seen some charts showing the difference in speed between POSIX semaphores and SYS V in the past (though it was in a book that's almost 20 years old), but I don't recall anything about the POSIX robust mutex (I didn't even know that existed).

Comment: Any reasonable implementation of the POSIX primitives is entirely userspace except in the contended case, and thus just takes roughly the number of cycles imposed by atomics and memory barriers. The sysv ipc objects, on the other hand, have permission, handle, and lifetime properties that make it necessary for the kernel to mediate any action on them. Even on the fastest machines the most trivial syscalls like `getpid` (the actual syscall, not the glibc cached result) take nearly 1000 cycles, and ones that do actual work take considerably more.

Comment: However I think you're right that sysv semaphores can be used to implement robust rwlocks, where a write lock is just decrementing the semaphore by the max allowed value which ensures there can be no readers, and with the kernel backout-on-process-death feature. I don't see any way to do this with the POSIX threads/semaphore primitives.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing a robust rwlock is actually quite difficult due to the "concurrent readers" property - a rwlock with bounded storage but an unbounded number of concurrent readers fundamentally cannot track who its readers are, so if knowledge of who the current readers are is to be kept (in order to decrement the current read lock count when a reader dies), it must be the reader tasks themselves, not the rwlock, which are aware of their ownership of it. I don't see any obvious way it can be built on top of robust mutexes, or on top of the underlying mechanisms (like `robust_list` on Linux) typically used to implement robust mutexes.

If you really need robust rwlock semantics, you're probably better off having some sort of protocol with a dedicated coordinator process that's assumed not to die, that tracks death of clients via closure of a pipe/socket to them and is able to tell via shared memory contents whether the process that died held a read lock. Note that this still involves implementing your own sort of rwlock.

Comment: I don't understand why a reader count can't just be kept in the lock? The OS increments the count when readers acquire the lock and decerements it when they unlock or exit.

Comment: @JosephGarvin: The point is that a count doesn't suffice; you have to know *who* the read lock owners are to know whether a dying task is one of them, since decrement on termination will be conditional on whether the task held a read lock (and how many it held).

Comment: Sure, but that's information the OS should have as long as users have to go through the kernel to increment/decrement the count. If we're worried about users mangling the data in shmem, the shmem rwlock could just store a handle (like an fd) representing the lock, and users would increment/decrement by giving the handle to the kernel.

Comment: @JosephGarvin: The whole modern design is that they don't have to go through the kernel to do that; if they did, it would be over 100x slower.  But even if they do go through the kernel, it doesn't help. You still need the exact same non-constant storage requirement. The kernel does not magically have infinite storage.

Comment: The kernel already needs to associate an arbitrarily large number of robust mutexes with any one PID, why would needing to associate an arbitrary number of PIDs with any one rwlock be worse? The kernel has to figure out variable length storage either way, and has to set upper limits to prevent memory exhaustion either way. This is what ulimits are for.

Comment: I'd be happy with a robust rwlock where you had to tell the kernel where you're keeping a userspace bool for whether you hold the lock and tell the kernel where the atomic count is, with the promise you'll set the bool to true before incrementing the lock counter, and the kernel guaranteeing that if your process cores it will use that bool to decide whether to decrement for you. Generally with 'robust' you're just trying to achieve unlocking on crash.

Comment: @JosephGarvin: You're **still** missing the point: there is nowhere to store that. With robust mutexes, there's a single owner, and the task can store the list of robust mutexes it owns for the kernel to process on termination as an intrinsic linked list within the mutex storage. With rwlocks, there are unboundedly many owners for read, and thus none of them can use storage within the rwlock to track ownership. Instead the task needs independent storage proportional to the number of rwlocks it holds (which is also unbounded) to keep track of what it owns read locks on.

Comment: I've already explained that this is not a real problem. In general, unbounded anything is not a problem, you set a cap and let admins decide when there is a legitimate reason to increase it. It's not correct to conclude it's impossible because it can't be implemented with one field on a task struct or one field on an rwlock struct.

Comment: @JosephGarvin: How do you handle the case where further storage is not available in a way that both conforms to the specification and admits any kind of forward progress or error recovery?

Comment: How do kernels deal with the fact that you can hit the file descriptor limit? What if there is no memory left to allocate more file descriptors?

Comment: @JosephGarvin: Opening a resource is an operation that can fail for lack-of-resources reasons; that's why you can't do it in code paths that necessarily must make forward progress (there has to be a way to back out what you're doing and error without opening anything). Taking a lock is not such an operation; it must be able to eventually make forward progress.

Comment: If it's so impossible why does Solaris support it? https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/3c/rwlock/

Answer (score 0):

> How can a process gracefully recover from a process crashing while holding a `rwlock`?

POSIX does not define a robustness option for its rwlocks.  If a process dies while holding one locked, the lock is not recoverable -- you cannot even `pthread_rwlock_destroy` it.  You also cannot expect any processes blocked trying to acquire the lock to unblock until their timeout, if any, expires.  Threads blocked trying unconditionally and without a timeout to acquire the lock cannot be unblocked even by delivering a signal, because POSIX specifies that if their wait is interrupted by a signal, they will resume blocking after the signal handler finishes.

Therefore, in the case that one of several cooperating processes dies while holding a shared rwlock locked, whether for reading or writing, the best possible result is probably to arrange for the other cooperating processes to shut down as cleanly as possible.  You shhould be able to arrange for something like that via a separate monitoring process that sends `SIGTERM`s to the others when a locking failure occurs.  There would need to be much more to it than that, though, probably including some kind of extra discipline or wrapping around acquiring the rwlock.

Honestly, if you want robustness then you're probably better off rolling your own read/write lock using, for example, POSIX robust mutexes and POSIX condition variables, as @R.. described in comments.

Consider also that robustness of the lock itself is only half the picture.  If a thread dies while holding the write lock, then you have the additional issue of ensuring the integrity of the data protected by the lock before continuing.